# Why do force.com sites domains have secure in the domain and some don't?

Tags: force.com-sites, security, custom-domain

In our production org, force.com sites have two endpoints listed

- `https://<ourdomain>.secure.force.com`
- `http://<ourdomain>.force.com`

It seems that these URLs can be used interchangeably and with either secure or insecure protocols, but then you get a cert error in using ssl on the one without secure in the URL.

- `https://<ourdomain>.secure.force.com`
- `http://<ourdomain>.secure.force.com` (cert mismatch warning)
- `https://<ourdomain>.force.com`
- `http://<ourdomain>.force.com`

However in sandboxes we only have one listed

- `http://<sandboxname>-<ourdomain>.<pod>.force.com`

And it can be accessed from both `http` and `https` protocols.

- `http://<sandboxname>-<ourdomain>.<pod>.force.com`
- `https://<sandboxname>-<ourdomain>.<pod>.force.com`

Is there any info about why the secure and insecure site domains are different in production? And why isn't the same pattern followed in production? Does it matter which insecure form we use in production?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

For HTTPS you should be using https://yourdomain.secure.force.com

The infrastructure for Sites in sandboxes is slightly different from production. For example, the CDN is only available for production orgs.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000230362&language=en_US